# Activate CSS Tab using external hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use PURE CSS TABS tab in my project but don't have idea how to select a tab using hyperlink: please see my code pen here:

```html
<a href="#specs">Select Speccification</a>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
    <label for="tab1">Description</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a id="specs"></a>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
    <label for="tab2">Specification</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
      <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla?</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<br style="clear: both;" />
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKWGmE)

What I want to achieve if user click on select specification  or show specification button the specification tab should be activated.

I think it can be achieved by javascript but I don't know how. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is jQuery version so don't forget to link jquery.js to your file
add this functuion to a js file.

```
function changeTab(){
  $('#tab2').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

then change this:

`<a href="#specs">Select Speccification</a>`

to this:

`<a href="#" onclick="changeTab();">Select Speccification</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="tab1">Tab1</a>

<div id="tabContent1">
    Tab1 Content
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#tab1').on('click', function(){
         $('#tabContent1').show();   
      })

  })
</script>
```

In CSS, by default, hide the content of `tabContent1`
You have to include jquery library in your script.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjaVNZ)

Comment: still cant get it right .. i m not that much familar with javacript. cant show me on codepen ? http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ojtal

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can do this in a pure CSS using `:target` selector
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp

```
<style>
    .tab {
        display: none;
    }

    .tab:target {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<div class="panel">
    <a href="#tab-1">tab 1 button</a>
    <a href="#tab-2">tab 2 button</a>
    <a href="#tab-3">tab 3 button</a>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab">tab 1 content</div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab">tab 2 content</div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab">tab 3 content</div>
</div>
```